# Theme suggestions file-video.html.twig

Tags: theming, files, 9

I have a block with the media field video bundle (drupal 9) and it renders the video through the file-video.html.twig. I have copied template to my custom theme from core. What do i need is to override it but only for the block field as i'm using media fields quite a lot in my website

Is there any chance to preprocess theme suggestions for file-video.html.twig template?

Comment: Have you seen the [Debugging Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) documentation?

Comment: @sonfd yes i have seen it. Template suggestions unfortunately not covering how to override media reference video template

Comment: You can use [hook_theme_suggestions_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) to add your own template suggestions.

Comment: @sonfd it works only to :

fields, media templates but not working to file-video template

Comment: @sonfd theme_suggestions_file_video_alter worked... now thinking how to implement better

Comment: How did you add suggestion? I wanted to add suggestions based on media display mode to file-video.html.twig?